# Server side textbox value is always empty string in case of webservice

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-tokeninput

I'm using tokenInput jquery plugin for autocomplete. This script is working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld7",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) { $("#<%=demo.ClientID %>").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but when I replace the line

```
$("#<%=demo.ClientID %>").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php");
```

with

```
$("#<%=demo.ClientID %>").tokenInput(data.d);
```

it shows me autocomplete, but in button click event it shows demo.Text as empty string.I checked the response in firebug and the response is

```
{"d":[{"__type":"TestForMySite.fb","Id":1,"name":"ALABAMA"},{"__type":"TestForMySite.fb","Id":2,"name":"ALASKA"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/), your JSON Array is not in the correct format. It should be:

```
[
    {"id":"856","name":"House"},
    {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
    ...
]
```

You have `Id` where it should be `id`.